# Specific Double Tap

Tags: android

I have zoomable image and I'm using `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`. I need to implement following items:

1. On Single Tap appear Toast with information about picture.
2. On Double Tap image is zooming.

I have some issue. Before Double Tap always is Single Tap and picture is zooming, but appear Toast. Is there any way to avoid Single Tap? I dont have enough savvy to solve this problem.

**P.S.** I **can't use `OnDoubleTapListener`** because use `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`.

**UPD**

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (Math.abs(firstTime-secondTime) < 300L) {
    // scale my matrix
    ---//---
    DONE = true; //this flag symbolize, that toast doesn't appear (false - appears)
    }
    else if (!DONE) {
         // making toast
    }
    secondTime = firstTime;
    break;
```

When DoubleTap is enable image scaled but appears toast

Comment: Wait half a second to listen for another tap before you show the "Toast", and don't show it if another tap occured?

Comment: Thank you. But how i can realized it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@matt5784, thank you. I was able to solve my problem.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    float xDiff =  Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
    float yDiff =  Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
    firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (Math.abs(firstTime-secondTime) > 200L) {
        myHand.postDelayed(mRun, 200);
    }
    else if (!DONE) {
        //scale my matrix
        DONE = true; //this flag symbolize, that toast doesn't appear (false - appears)
    }
    secondTime = firstTime;
    break;

Handler myHand = new Handler();
private Runnable mRun = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!DONE) {
                     // make toast
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing a delay where the information doesn't pop up immediately on a single tap, but only is displayed if it doesn't encounter a second tap within a reasonable amount of time (probably whatever your threshold for double-taps is). I.e. if it is set up to register any taps within .2 seconds as a double tap, don't display the info until you have waited .2 secs and are sure there isn't a double tap.

Alternate solution (probably less useful) - have the double tap/zoom function call whatever function makes the information box disappear. However it will probably still pop up for a very short amount of time which may look silly/be problematic.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I thought about 1st solve of problem, but I couldn't to implement this. Have I to use thread or wait()? If you are easily could you demonstrate it on sample code?

Comment: Well, how are you checking for double taps? just use the same thing you are using to check for double taps to trigger the info...